# Why used import statement is specified as "unused import statement" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio and build as "Generate Signed APK...". And I faced the error, "Unused import statement" like following.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  // <- specified as unused ERROR
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;   // <- specified as unused ERROR
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;        // <- specified as unused ERROR
import android.util.Log;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
...
}
```

But I can easily see FragmentActivity is used in code. How can I fix it? This error happens all over my codes...

Comment: Just clean and rebuild the project. This might happen once you have included the packages and later on there is not any usage of that class

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding your project

Comment: When rebuilding, there's an error that "Can't delete app/build folder". So I manually deleted the folder, changed settings "Optimize imports on the fly" off, and rebooted Android Studio. Then Clean -> Rebuild works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have "Optimize imports on the fly" enabled, which automatically removes unused imports. You likely also have "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" selected, which automatically adds imports you need. The solution is to write the code first, and watch your imports be added automatically, and manually add any ambiguous ones, as they become needed. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html?search=optim

In the event this does not work for you, or if you simply prefer to enter your own import statements, then simply disable the features in settings > Editor > Auto Import.

Answer (score 1):

When I updated the android studio to 3.3.1 I go this error.
Solved it by updating the libraries and compileSdkVersion to the latest version that is 27. Hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the problem in the Android studio 3.2.1. Invalidate and delete ./idea does not work. It disappear when I upgrade  3.4.1.