# I can't import android.text.Editable

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I've just been to began  android app with beginner books
That book use "android text  Editable" 
cause I  tried to import text Editable but  i can't it
Then I found:

[Why used import statement is specified as "unused import statement" in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698859/why-used-import-statement-is-specified-as-unused-import-statement-in-android-s)

As above  I removed "Optimize imports  on the fly " 
But don't disappear yet
Why I can't import `android.text.Editable`
Someone teach me, please.
just in case I use android studio latest version.

Comment: Simple, because you haven't used it yet, i think. May be below line 27, add this: `Editable medit;` you will see it change the color text to black

Comment: everyone  Thanks  Have a niceday

Comment: Hope you already understand why

Comment: Sorry I have no idea ,What do you mean?